What does diversity of letter writers mean and is it important?
I am reapplying for grad school in the US. In the last cycle, I got interviewed at a top school of my choice but eventually did not make it. Upon inquiring into what the reasons might be, I got the feedback from a committee member that I should work on having greater diversity of letter writers and continue working in other countries.
Last year, I had 3 recommenders, 2 from my native country and one from Europe.
All of these professors worked in fields similar to what I wanted to pursue. I had worked with an American professor (then postdoc) early in my undergraduate studies but since then my interests have moved in a completely different direction. Also, since I worked with them as a very inexperienced young student in a very limited capacity, I don't think their letter will reflect my abilities as well as the ones I submitted in the last cycle. They also let me know that the letter will possibly not be as personalised as ideal.
Other aspects of my application have evolved including conferences and posters but this aspects remains more or less the same. Would it be better to stick to the previous letter writers or replace one with the new recommendation to act on the feedback?

The question in the title and given in the body are very different. The one in the title seems good, whereas the one that closes the body asks for an opinion which is less well-suited for the Q&A format.


I got interviewed at a top school of my choice but eventually did not make it

Nice work! Once you get to the interview stage, you've basically passed the application. At that point, you could destroy your chances if you're a real jerk in person, but otherwise it's mostly a dice roll: they're going to invite people to interviews that they want to accept, but ultimately they have to draw a line somewhere and accept only some number based on slots available.
You probably should have applied more broadly if you only had one interview, especially if it was at a top school. That gives you more chances to get to the interview stage and more chances to beat the dice roll once you get there. With only one interview, it's not really possible to say you've done anything wrong. You're up against other good candidates like yourself.

I got the feedback from a committee member that I should work on having greater diversity of letter writers and continue working in other countries. Last year, I had 3 recommenders, 2 from my native country and one from Europe.

I think this is slightly weird advice, given you made it to the interview stage. However, ultimately they're going to have to make a choice between otherwise similar candidates. I think reading between the lines, unfortunately they probably mean "I/we don't trust recommendations from your native country".
If it comes down to comparing two candidates who are otherwise promising, if one has letters written from institutions that they don't recognize, it's hard to know what value those letters have. Maybe you're only the best student they've ever seen because most of the students at that institution aren't any good. That's not really fair, but I think that's what they mean.

Abstractly the comment 'more diversity of letter writers' could also mean something like 'we would prefer if not all letter writers are white-cis-males'. However, from context OP seems to be from a country outside North America/ Western Europe and have letter writers from their home country. Therefore this interpretation seems very unlikely and the interpretation in this answer seems way more likely.

@quarague - sadly my interpretation would be "we don't really care about letters from your irrelevant country", so not sexism but still bigotry.

Thank you for your insights. I did apply for and get into 2 other institutes in the last cycle but they somehow did not have any interviews. I was not able to attend any of these schools last cycle due to personal reasons. Since I am applying again, I'd prefer to apply to this place again but this comment really confused me especially because there's an upper limit of 3 letters only. I have no idea how to go about this limitation.

@DazedAndConfused I see. If you've continued to do useful things since your last application (conferences and posters would count), I think you have a good chance; if not, you may have missed your chance when you chose not to attend programs that admitted you. Remember that even if your profile improves, you compete against a new batch of applicants each year, and the difference between "admit" or "not admit" can be just one person who they end up ranking above you. I would definitely apply to more than just the schools you applied to last time.

I don't think they are asking for more letters, I think they're trying to communicate that some of your letters are unconvincing because they're coming from sources that are not seen as impressive. I can't tell you whether to replace any of your letter writers, all these things are judged by individuals who each have their own intentional or unintentional criteria. I agree that reaching back to an advisor with different interests for an impersonal letter does not seem like an upgrade, but who knows.

@quarague and what exactly would be the motivation for rejecting students because their recommenders are male? And do you expect the committee to call the recommenders and ask them if they are trans? Because they are not going to write that in the letter.

This comment about "diversity" may be only one person's opinion, but I read it as a suggestion that on some scale your letter writers are too similar to one another. Even more likely, is that they are all saying the same thing about you, meaning that there is, in effect, only one letter.
Alternatively, since you have changed fields, it might be a (poorly worded) suggestion that you need letter writers from that or a closely aligned field in order to have them have more impact.
I can't promise that, of course,
The "other countries" comment is even harder to parse, but might depend on your field.
And, as the answer of Bryan Krause notes, cast a wide net for applications to graduate study, not just "top" schools, but a fairly wide range. That might be the key, especially if you are applying with only an undergraduate degree.
